# Using "infinite bounds" in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to maximize a 3 variable function, which is defined in the following space:

]0, ∞[ x ]1, ∞[  x [0, ∞[

I am going to use SLSQP algorithm from scipy.optimize.minimize and I was thinking it should be done defining bounds for the function. But I don't know how to write "infinity" in python or this limits. Maybe it should be done using, then, constraints, but I couldnt find a way to define it.

I would be glad if I could get some help doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)'s documentation states that:

> **bounds** : sequence, optional
>
> Bounds for variables (only for L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP). `(min, max)` pairs for each element in `x`, defining the bounds on that
>   parameter. **Use `None` for one of min or max when there is no bound in
>   that direction.**

So you don't have to represent infinity, just pass `None`. Passing the floating point infinity *may* not work as intended.

---

The standard way to represent infinity in python is using `float('inf')` for plus infinity and `float('-inf')` for minus infinity. These represent the standard IEEE 754 infinity values.

`numpy` also offers `numpy.inf`.

Comment: Is this also true for the bounds argument of minimize_scalar https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html ?

Comment: @Adrian It seems that that function only needs a single pair of values. It says that `bounds` is a sequence of two items. That's because `minimize_scalar` is for functions in *one* variable. Moreover it seems like only with `method='bounded'` the bounds are actually used, in the other cases they are ignored. See [the last example on this page.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html)